# Polymer 1.0: reference selected iron-list item in CSS

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to highlight the selected item from an `iron-list`. However, I can't seem to find any property to track in CSS to apply a highlight to the selected item specifically. My template code looks like this:

```
<iron-list items="[[fileCells]]" as="item" selection-enabled>
  <template>
    <paper-icon-item on-tap="_onItemTap">
      <iron-icon icon="[[item.iconName]]" item-icon></iron-icon>
      <paper-item-body two-line>
        <div>[[item.fileName]]</div>
        <div secondary>[[item.progressValue]]</div>
      </paper-item-body>
    </paper-icon-item>
  </template>
</iron-list>
<array-selector id="selector" items="{{fileCells}}" selected="{{selected}}" toggle></array-selector>
```

The cells are displaying correctly, and I can capture taps on the items. Before I started implementing the `iron-list`, I had some static `paper-icon-item` elements inside an `iron-selector` element. I could easily style the selected element like so:

```
paper-icon-item.iron-selected {
  background: #B2EBF2;
}
```

But this no longer works in the dynamic `iron-list` implementation, since the `class` property of `paper-icon-item` doesn't seem to be updating upon being selected. Is there another property I can track to style only the selected item? Would re-implementing `iron-selector` somewhere help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `selected` property, but it is not reflected to a class. You could do that manually by listening to changes to the `selected` property and updating the class in a computed binding.

```
<paper-icon-item class$="[[_computeClass(selected)]]">
```

In the prototype implement the function, for example like this.

```
_computeClass : function(selected) {
     return selected? "selected": "";
}
```

Then you can use the `selected`class in your CSS.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me find a solution. In this particular case, I couldn't set the `class` in this way, because I'm using `paper-icon-item` elements as cells, which have their own generated classes that Polymer sets. Setting the `class` explicitly threw things off. Instead, I computed a custom `id` based on `selected`, and it works for me.

Comment: I even think that the 'selected' property is not being set anymore since iron-list v 1.4.x   ?

Comment: It does work in 1.4.x, you just have to use the `selection-enabled` attribute for it to trigger.